# Multiple Values using single Criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]I need help with my office work.
I am trying to look for a formula where I have one database that contains the list of all supervisors and all their analyst (15 per team).

I have tried

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!$A$1:$A$350,SMALL(IF($F$7=Database!$I$1:$I$350,ROW(Database!$A$1:$A$350)-1,""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

What I am trying to do is I want to do a lookup using the supervisors list and employee id list and it will show all their emp id on the yellow part.

I have updated a screenshot of the idea,

Comment: How about choose(), and choose a particular list of analysts according to the matching supervisor across the top.

Comment: How is your data set up? Do you have two columns? One with supervisors and one with analysts? That's what your formula looks like any way.

Comment: @JvdV Yes! The column E:F is my Database. The criteria is Cell C1 & C16. The value should go in the yellow part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is been set up in two columns, you might look into use of `SMALL`. It's an array solution though:

***Google Spreadsheets:***

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($F$1:$F$27,SMALL(($G$1:$G$27=$C$1)*ROW($G$1:$G$27),COUNTIF($G$1:$G$27,"<>"&C$1)+ROW(A1))))
```

***Excel:***

Same formula (almost) but entered as array using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$27,SMALL(($G$1:$G$27=$C$1)*ROW($G$1:$G$27),COUNTIF($G$1:$G$27,"<>"&C$1)+ROW(A1)))
```

You can replicate the formula for `C17` but just need to edit the cell reference to `C17`. Drag the formula down.

Comment: Now, I like the excel version, also finally worked out that it is entered as an array into cell C3 and THEN dragged down... :)   Will be updating some of my workbooks now... plus 1 then.

Answer (score 2):

So, have a look at this:
(Note, submitted before the source data structure was evident, but left as it may be a helpful solution for others...)

[image]

Cell B2 is a drop down from data validation to select the supervisor you want to work with.

Drag the choose down for the number you need.

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: I have given you the formula used in cell D2, which is just dragged down. Cell B2 as used in the match is the supervisor you wish to target...

Comment: Nice, I always like `CHOOSE`. Maybe a suggestion though, with this data setup `INDEX` + `MATCH` might be less tedious to use on 15 columns.

Comment: I have updated my post above and attached an image. Hope that  could be helpful

Comment: @Captionless I'll leave my answer "as is" but making your data format clear at the start would have helped.

Comment: @SolarMike, very true. I also thought you had it there.

Answer (score 1):

paste in **C2** cell:

```
=FILTER(F:F, G:G=C1)
```

paste in **C17** cell:

```
=FILTER(F:F, G:G=C16)
```

[image: 0]

---

also you could just use:

```
=FILTER(F:F, G:G=INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is nice! clean and simple! Should be the answer. But you can't remove tags like that.

Comment: OPs app is GS **not** Excel << its clear enough from the picture